# Compare PHP foreach items and increment

Tags: php, codeigniter, loops, foreach

I am using codeigniter to build table organizing users of an office, according to how many times someone uses the office. So the table will include, a username, number of uses, and a rank/position where the user who used the office the most times (has the highest number of uses) is at the top. Like a game leader board where the user with the highest score is at the top.

I have this code:

```
<?php $i=1;?>
<?php foreach ($leaders as $item):?>
    <?php if($i==11) break; ?>
<tr>
    <td><?= $i++; ?></td>
    <td><?= $item['Name']; ?></td>
    <td><?= $item['Uses']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

This code lists the users with the most uses from highest to lowest. **It shows the top 10.**

However, if a more than one user has the same number of uses, the positions on the table are different because I increment the position $i for each item in the loop.

I tried this code but it doesn't quite work as I want it.

```
<?php
$i=1;
$uses=null;
?>
<? foreach ($leaders as $item): 
    if($i==11) break; 

    if ($uses== $item['Uses']) {
        $i=$i;
    } else {
        $i=$i++;
    }
?>
<tr>
    <td><?= $i; ?></td>
    <td><?= $item['Name']; ?></td>
    <td><?= $item['Uses']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?= $uses=$item['Uses']; ?>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

How do I fix this so that users with the same number of uses show at the same position. Example if John, Mary and Carl all have 5 uses, they should all have position 2 (`$i`), and not 2, 3,4.

So that all users with the same number of uses `$item['Uses'];`, have the same position `$i`.

**EDIT**

Trying to achieve something like this:

```
$previous_value = 0;
foreach ($arr as $key=>$value) {
    echo $key .'=>'. $previous_value .' '.  $value;
    $previous_value = $value;
}
```

I basically want to say, if uses == previous item uses, then $i is the same as the $i in the prev item in loop, else, $i++

Comment: "_It shows the top 10_" Only if the array has already been sorted by `uses`.

Comment: I like your first sentence... "I am suing codeigniter" :-)

Comment: Why do you have `$i=$i;`?

Comment: You don't have to do `<? ... ?>` for EVERY line of php code. if you've got multiple lines of php code, then open the tag ONCE, have your multiple lines, then close it.

Comment: @dave I was trying to get that if the uses for the previous users is the same as this users, the the position i should be the same, else increment it by one.

Comment: @AbraCadaver $leaders array has been sorted by uses in the controller, and passed to the view as $leaders

Comment: @MarcB I'd think something along the lines of "You *have* not to do `<? ... ?>`" ... :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, let's say you have ordered your users, you should only have 10 in your foreach (try using a limit 10 in your SQL query, or extracting them from the array), and you'd avoid having to use a break inside of it. Nevermind, your problem is what to do with that users repeated. You'll only have to check if the previous value is repeated. If not, increase and keep going. Below you have a PHP file with the loop, is a standalone file, you can copy-paste and run it and you'll have your list:

```
<?php
$users = array(
    array('name'  => 'user1',   'uses'  => 30)
,   array('name'  => 'user2',   'uses'  => 30)
,   array('name'  => 'user3',   'uses'  => 22)
,   array('name'  => 'user4',   'uses'  => 20)
,   array('name'  => 'user5',   'uses'  => 16)
,   array('name'  => 'user6',   'uses'  => 16)
,   array('name'  => 'user7',   'uses'  => 15)
,   array('name'  => 'user8',   'uses'  => 10)
);

$position  = 1;    
$prev_uses = $users[0]['uses'];
foreach ( $users as $user ) {
    if ( $prev_uses != $user['uses'] ) {
        $position++;
    }
    echo $position . ' - Name: ' . $user['name'] . ' Values: ' . $user['uses'] . '<br>';
    $prev_uses  = $user['uses'];
}
```

The most important thing is the initial value, as you see, I initialize it in `$prev_uses` with the value of the first user.

If you'd do need to use the break (I suggest you not to use it to avoid unnecessary checks), the modification would be:

```
$position   = 1; 
$user_count = 1;   
$prev_uses  = $users[0]['uses'];
foreach ( $users as $user ) {
    if ( $user_count == 11 ) {
        break;
    } else {
        $user_count++;
    }
    if ( $prev_uses != $user['uses'] ) {
        $position++;
    }
    echo $position . ' - Name: ' . $user['name'] . ' Values: ' . $user['uses'] . '<br>';
    $prev_uses  = $user['uses'];
}
```

As you see, you need two vars to keep counting, XD

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your array already ordered by uses. You can replace this line:

First do that:

```
<?php 
    $uses = array('','');
    foreach ($leaders as $item):?>
<?= $uses=$item['Uses']; ?>
```

by

```
<?php $uses=array($i,$item['Uses']); ?>
```

So you can do that:

```
<?php
if ($uses[1] == $item['Uses']){
$i=$uses[0];
else{
$i=$i++;
}
?>
```

Comment: This gave me the same result. I edited some of the OP to show what i am trying ti achieve